# In a Java-webapp (war), how can I use HTTP-auth for static content?

Tags: java, web-applications, war, web.xml

I have a Java-webapp. The webapp is packaged as a war-file. These war-file allow static content, that is directly delivered via HTTP. For servlets in this war I can make a HTTP-authentication (implement it with the servlet itself). But I also want HTTP-auth for the static content. How can I realize this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a class that implements javax.servlet.Filter. See [The Essentials of Filters](http://java.sun.com/products/servlet/Filters.html)

The main method is doFilter that is passed the ServletRequest, ServletResponse and FilterChain objects. That's where you enforce authentication.

Then declare your filter in web.xml and a filter mapping as following (maps to every request)

```
    <filter>
            <filter-name>Authentication Filter</filter-name>
            <filter-class>
                    com.nfsdsystems.security.filters.AuthenticationFilter</filter-class>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
            <filter-name>Authentication Filter</filter-name>
            <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
```

Answer (score 3):

Put your static html files in a direcotry and define your security constraints in your web.xml. Map the constraints to the appropriate role.

```
<security-constraint>
        <display-name>securedResources</display-name>
        <web-resource-collection>
            <web-resource-name>securedRes</web-resource-name>
            <url-pattern>/secured/*</url-pattern>
            <http-method>GET</http-method>
            <http-method>PUT</http-method>
            <http-method>HEAD</http-method>
            <http-method>TRACE</http-method>
            <http-method>POST</http-method>
            <http-method>DELETE</http-method>
            <http-method>OPTIONS</http-method>
        </web-resource-collection>
        <auth-constraint>
            <description>
            authenticatedUser_securedRes</description>
            <role-name>authenticatedUsed</role-name>
        </auth-constraint>
    </security-constraint>
```

Comment: That would indeed be the prefered way to do it using realms.

Comment: How I can define the usernames/passwords this way?

Comment: It depends of the app server you are using. For Tomcat, google "jdbc realm configuration". For websphere, the prefered way would be ldap.

Comment: As I want to only deploy a war with my application and no further configuration needed, I prefer the Filter-solution, sorry. But your answer is also good, upvote.